# Mongodb query that transforms GeoJSON 3d coordinates to 2d coordinates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geojson

I've a collection with a field populated by a GeoJSON 3d coordinate called "Confini" that I want to index for a 2d geospatal query so I need to transform it to a 2d coordinate by removing the third element.

The "Confini" field looks like this:

```
"Confini" : {
"type" : "Polygon",
"coordinates" : [[[16.685926, 38.961437, 0.0], [16.685612, 38.961475, 0.0],[16.685926, 38.961437, 0.0]]]
}
```

I tried this query:

```
{ $pull: { "Confini.coordinates.0.$": 0.0 }}



var cursor = db.City.find({});
var i=0;
cursor.forEach(function(x){
    db.City.update({ "Confini.coordinates.0" : x.Confini.coordinates } ,{ $pull: { x.Confini : 0.0}});
});
```

With the aim of deleting the third element of each item in the coordinates array but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you willing to do this in client code? I think you would be better off rebuilding the 2d polygon in a loop and then doing an update based on _id.

Comment: Yes, I could do it with a client using the C# or Java driver (and now I'm working on it) but I was wondering if I could do it directly through Query.

Comment: I don't think so. GeoJSON is a somewhat special format within Mongo, and I don't think there is a general method for accessing multidimensional arrays in a single query like this.